# A C function for returning the address of the calling function

Tags: c, windows, reflection, assembly

Suppose you are given two functions, `foo` and `bar`, and neither of them are inlined. Now, if `foo` calls for `bar` and `bar` calls for `called_from`, `bar` receives the address of the caller, that is, the address of `foo`. I know that there is no real need for such computation as it is always possible to simply pass an enumeration that indicates the caller, yet I was in the mood for hacking the stack.

My code compiles on Visual Studio.

**main.cpp**:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/************************************************************************
* Suppose that foo() calls for bar() and bar() calls for called_from(). *
* Now if neither bar() and foo() are inlined functions, bar() receives  *
* the address of foo() from the function called_from().                 *
************************************************************************/
void* called_from() {
    __asm {
        mov eax, [ebp] 
        mov eax, [eax]     // foo's ebp
        mov eax, [eax + 4] // foo's return address
        mov edx, eax;      // we might need a copy of
                           // the foo's return address

        sub eax, 5;        // the adress of the instruction 'call foo'
        mov bl, [eax]      // the opcode of the call instruction
        inc eax            // [eax] points to the address of foo

        mov eax, [eax];    // load the caller's address

        cmp bl, 0xE8
        je RelationalAddress // the address is relational

        cmp bl, 0xFF
        je Exit              // the adress is absolute
        jmp Abort

        RelationalAddress:
        add eax, edx         // convert relational address
                             // to an abolute one
        jmp Exit

        Abort:
        mov eax, 0           // failure, return null pointer
        Exit: 
    }
}

// We need the macro as otherwise it will obscure the actual caller.
#define is_called_from(n) (called_from() == (void*) n)
```

Here are a few tests:

> ```
> void foo();
> void bar();
> void baz();
>
> int main() {
>   printf(
>       "main:\t0x%p\n"
>       "foo: \t0x%p\n"
>       "bar: \t0x%p\n"
>       "baz: \t0x%p\n"
>       "\n",
>       main,
>       foo,
>       bar,
>       baz);
>
>   foo();
>   bar();
>   baz();
>
>   getchar();
>   return 0;
> }
>
> void foo() {
>   printf("This is foo:\n"
>          "called from %p\n"
>          "that is, from ",
>          called_from());
>
>   if (is_called_from(main))
>   {
>       puts("main.\n");
>   }
>   else if (is_called_from(bar))
>   {
>       puts("bar.\n");
>   }
>   else
>   {
>       puts("somewhere else.\n");
>   }
> }
>
> void bar() {
>   printf("This is bar:\n"
>          "called from 0x%p\n"
>          "\n",
>          called_from());
>
>   foo();
> }
>
> void baz() {
>   printf("This is baz:\n"
>          "called from 0x%p\n"
>          "\n",
>          called_from());
>
>   foo();
> }
> ```

Comment: It doesn't handle indirect calls, does it?

Comment: In the terminology described in the comment above, do you mean the case where `bar` is actuall assigned to a function pointer and then called?

Comment: After googling for 'indirect call'... No, it does not handle it. It sees 'through' it.

Comment: When `foo` was called via register (pointer).

Comment: If `called_from` is being executed (topmost stack frame \$n\$), it tampers with the stack frame \$n - 2\$. Oh, man, I dunno.

Comment: Then the address of the function register-calling `foo` is returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Didn't totally work

After porting the code to gnu C style, it only "sort of" worked for me.  I was able to have `foo()` print that it was called from `bar()` or `baz()`.  However, if `foo()` was called directly from `main()`, then it crashed when trying to find its caller.  That's probably because on my system (Cygwin 32-bit, using Gnu C compiler), `main()` doesn't have a caller on the stack.

## Clobbered register

It's not safe to write to `ebx` without pushing it on the stack and popping it off later.  `ebx` is considered non-volatile, which means that a function must preserve its value.  If you don't, then the calling function will be affected because its local variable may be stored in `ebx`, for example.  You can safely use `eax`, `ecx`, and `edx` though, because they are all considered volatile registers (i.e. you are allowed to clobber them).  So you should change your `ebx` accesses to `ecx` instead.

## Not portable

Your asm statement assumes that the compiler will insert these lines at the top of the function:

```
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
```

That may be what your compiler does, but it's not a certainty.  For example, with my GNU C compiler, it normally outputs the above code.  But with the -O2 option, it does this instead:

```
    subl    $28, %esp
```

If you want to make sure that you get the function prologue you need, you should write the whole thing in assembly and include the prologue/epilogue you require.